# MEAN Stack - Connect Cloud MongoDB to Angular Application?

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I think I may be missing something, as I have not used MongoDB much.

How do I connect my Angular application to a MongoDB database that I can access via Atlas? Currently, I can connect the app to a local MongoDB database without any issues, but I can't find anything to do with linking the app to a live database.

**server.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// Models
import Invoice from './server/models/Invoice.model';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/[myDatabaseName]', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
})

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', _ => {
  console.log('MongoDB database connection established');
})

app.use('/', router);

router.route('/invoices').get((req, res) => {
  Invoice.find({}, (err, invoices) => {
    res.json(invoices);
  })
})

router.route('/invoices/:id').get((req, res) => {
  Invoice.findById(req.params.invoiceId, (err, invoice) => {
    res.json(invoice);
  })
})

router.route('/invoices').post((req, res) => {
  let newInvoice = new Invoice(req.body);
  newInvoice.save()
    .then(invoice => {
        res.status(200).send(invoice);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send('Failed to save new invoice');
    })
  })

  router.route('/invoice/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    Invoice.findById(req.params.id, (err, invoice => {
      if (!invoice) {
        return next(new Error('Unable to find invoice'));
      } else {
        invoice.save()
            .then(invoice => {
                res.json('Successfully updated invoice', invoice);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send('Error updating invoice', err);
            })
      }
    }))
})

router.route('/invoices/delete/:id').get((req, res) => {
  Invoice.findByIdAndRemove({
    id: req.params.id
  }, (err, invoice) => {
    if (err) {
        res.json(err);
    } else {
        res.json('Successfully deleted invoice');
    }
  })
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log(`Express server running on port 4000`);
})
```

**invoices.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';

import Invoice from '@app/interfaces/invoice.interface';
import { NotificationsService } from '@app/services/notifications/notifications.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class InvoicesService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:4000';

  constructor(private notificationsService: NotificationsService, private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getInvoices() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/invoices`);
  }

}
```

Comment: Change "localhost" in the `mongoose.connect` to the actual live database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hosted my MongoDB in mlab and i am connecting using the lines below. Check if this is useful for you

```
const db = "mongodb://user:pass@dsxxxxx.mlab.com:port/poc"
mongoose.connect(db, err =>{
if(err){
    console.log('Error! '+ err)
}else{
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb')
}
```

})

Comment: Thanks. Having seen this, it reminded me of the pattern of MongoDB connection URI strings, which I've since looked at and been able to use to connect to the database. How have you been able to add URI's for HTTP requests in your application?

Comment: I am using like this to form URI for http requests const api = require('./routes/api')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello from server')
})

app.get('/uri1i', api)
app.get('/uri2', api)
app.get('/usr3', api)
app.get('/uri4', api) . I wrote my logic in api.js what each URI does